# Proof involving relation properties

Tags: functions, relations

Let, $Z$ = $\mathbb{N}$ $*$ $\mathbb{N}$ and ~ be the relation defined as follows:

$(a,b)$ ~ $(c,d)$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $a + d = b + c$

I have been asked to prove this relation is reflexive and symmetric. My attempt:

***proof (by direct proof)***

Reflexivity $\rightarrow$ $(a,b)$ ~ $(a,b)$ $\rightarrow$$  a+b = b+a$.

$\therefore$ by the commutivity of $\mathbb{N}$ this is clearly true.

Thus, ~ is reflexive.

Symmetric $\rightarrow$ $(c,d)$ ~ $(a,b)$ $\rightarrow$$  c+b= d+a$.

$\therefore$ the commutivity of $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $  b+c= a+d$ $\rightarrow$ $(a,b)$  ~ $(c,d)$.

Thus, ~ is symmetric.

$\blacksquare$

Is this sufficient? I understand I was vague in parts of the proof but this is simply since I was short on time. Are all my assumptions/reasoning logical?

Comment: This is perfectly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good to me.

There is one small detail you can use to make it go faster (barring concerns about circular logic*), namely that
$$
a + d = b + c
$$
is equivalent to 
$$
a-b = c-d
$$
which makes things easier.

*Your relation is, technically, how the integers and subtraction are constructed from the naturals and addition (with $(n, 0)$ and all pairs related to it being the integer $n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$, and then $-n$ is given by $(0,n)$ and all pairs related to that). So depending on your level it would be circular to approach it like this.